# How do I create a Login page using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, forms-authentication

I would like to create a login page using ASP.NET. I don't want to use the ASP.NET login control.

How do I do this?

Comment: Try posting specific code, or being more specific about your question. Do you already know asp/.net?

Comment: Hmmm, I know a guy who had this as a job interview test.

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki if it's not already here and a dupe.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe why you do not want to use the asp.net login control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following article on the MSDN website has a very good treatment of ASP.NET Forms Authentication which I think you'll find helpful.

> [Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0 (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)

Comment: Google is all very well, but if you don't know what it's called, how do you google for it? Why not just answer the question and get rep for being smart. :)

Comment: See look, I just upvoted because your answer is now much better :)